# How to pass object to animation function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, animation, pass-by-reference

I have been trying to make a JavaScript animation of moving circle in HTML Canvas without using global variables. I am using requestAnimationFrame function. Since JavaScript does not support passing variable by reference, I tried creating a Circle class:

```
class Circle{
  constructor(x, y, dx, dy) //set initial position and velocity of circle
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
  }
}

function moveCircle(circle, other variables)
{
  //clear canvas
  //calculate new position and velocity using circle.x, etc.
  //save new values to the object
  //draw new circle into the canvas

  requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle);
}

function button()//function called after click on button
{
  //initial settings of canvas, intial condition

  circle = new Circle(x, y, dx, dy);
  moveCircle(circle, other vars);
}
```

This makes one frame and then throws error "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined". What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way of doing this, while avoiding global variables?

Comment: Read the docs on `requestAnimationFrame` - you cannot pass arguments _with_ the handler to it, the handler only receives `time` as an argument. You are also needlessly creating new circle objects over and over. You would need some sort of global or scoped variable so the function can remember your circle and move it around. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create a class you can just pass the coordinates in an object or as separate arguments.
Secondly you should use `Function#bind` on `requestAnimationFrame` to pass the same arguments to next call.

Example using object:

```js
function moveCircle(circle) {
  console.log(circle.x);
  if (circle.x) {
    circle.x -= circle.dx;
    requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle.bind(null, circle));
  }
}

function button() {
  moveCircle({
    x: 500,
    y: 0,
    dx: 20,
    dy: 0
  });
}

button();
```

Example without object:

```js
function moveCircle(x, dx) {
  console.log(x);
  if (x) {
    requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle.bind(null, x - dx, dx));
  }
}

function button() {
  moveCircle(500, 20);
}

button();
```

Comment: Why do you use bind here? Is there any benefit using bind instead of just using `() => moveCircle(circle)`? I've never understood why people use it :)

Comment: @Kobe You could use `() => moveCircle(circle)` or `function(){moveCircle(circle);}`. I just find bind cleaner, since you don't create a new scope that you don't need.

Comment: @Kobe It's also a lot cleaner in a case like `setTimeout(this.test.bind(test))` where the equivalent of a function would be `var self = this; setTimeout(function(){self.test.call(self);});`

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple you could use a `closure` to create a handler that internally knows what your circle looks like and how it should move. A closure is simply a function that defines its own variables locally, then returns a function that can access those.

We want to return a function that only accepts one argument: `time`, since that is the argument passed into every handler in the AnimationFrame by the browser. Then we want the closure function to draw into the globally defined canvas. Have a look here:

```js
const canvas = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'canvas' ) );

function makeMovingCircle( canvas, x, y, radius, distance, duration ){
  
  // Lets get the context to draw here so we only need to fetch it once and store it, saving some computing time in favour of storing into memory.
  
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  
  // We need to return a named function here so it can interally call itself again in requestAnimationFrame
  
  return function AnimationHandler( time ){
    
    // Lets just calculate an offset here based on the distance and duration we passed in above.
    
    const progress = (time % duration / duration) * distance;
    
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( x + progress, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true );
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // Now call the named handler for the next animationFrame

    window.requestAnimationFrame( AnimationHandler );
    
  }
  
}

// Now lets make an animation handler and add it to the animationFrame. If you ever want to cancel it, you might want to store it in a global variable though so you can call cancelAnimationFrame on it.

window.requestAnimationFrame(
  makeMovingCircle( canvas, 15, 15, 10, 100, 2000 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick example from my memory:

```js
const circle = $('#circle');

class Main {
  constructor() {

  }

  start() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this))
  }

  loop() {
    const pos = circle.position();
    // speed is a constant 1,1. But you could replace it by a variable
    circle.css({top: pos.top+1, left: pos.left+1, position:'absolute'});
    requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this))
  }
}

const main = new Main();
main.start();
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="circle" src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" 
       alt="PlayCode logo">
  <h1 id="msg"></h1>
</div>
```

```css
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

In js, object are passed by reference, and primitive types by value.
I think you should avoid having other variables in moveCircle function. That kind of function is usually called "loop" or "gameLoop" or "update". When your button is clicked, add a speed to the circle, without creating a new circle, something like `myCircle.speed = {x:2, y:2}`. In the gameloop, add the speed to the position each frame.

Think also about delta time, as requestAnimationFrame will be faster depending on the PC/Mobile that run it.

You can wrap your application into on Main class if you like. (like I did above)

Finnaly, if you insist passing parameters to `moveCircle`, you can use `bind`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```js
function c(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a); console.log(b); console.log(c);
}

c.bind(window, 4,3)
// function c() // bind will return a function ! In a class usually the context that you want to pass is `this`. If you are playing directly in the console, the context is window by default (not that it matter in this example)

c.bind(window, 4,3)()
// 4
// 3
// undefined
```

The first call to moveCircle (from what I understand, it is in button function), should also be a `requestAnimationFrame` like `requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle.bind(window, other vars))`, you could re-use that in moveCircle as well, to avoid any global variable. Still, I recommend making a class to wrap your application, so that you can use local variables to your class to save the current state of your game instead of having that same state living inside the function arguments only.